# Unable to change the state of a custom widget with ProviderPackage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a icon that is on top of a map, Basically it is a location pin icon. I want to show or hide when a button is clicked.
Initially I have set the visibility to hide but then when I click the button it wont show

Here is the code for the widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MapPickerController {
  Function? mapMoving;
  Function? mapFinishedMoving;
}

class MapPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Widget iconWidget;
  final bool showDot;
  final MapPickerController mapPickerController;
  final bool showMapPicker;

  MapPicker(
      {required this.mapPickerController,
      required this.iconWidget,
      this.showDot = true,
      required this.child,
      required this.showMapPicker});

  @override
  _MapPickerState createState() => _MapPickerState();
}

class _MapPickerState extends State<MapPicker>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    widget.mapPickerController.mapMoving = mapMoving;
    widget.mapPickerController.mapFinishedMoving = mapFinishedMoving;
  }

  void mapMoving() {
    (widget.showMapPicker);
    if (!animationController.isCompleted || !animationController.isAnimating) {
      animationController.forward();
      print("Map Moving");
    }
  }

  void mapFinishedMoving() {
    animationController.reverse();
    print("Map Finished Moving");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        widget.child,
        Container(),
        if (widget.showMapPicker)
          AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animationController,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset(0, -10 * animationController.value),
                        child: widget.iconWidget,
                      ),
                      if (widget.showDot)
                        Container(
                          width: 5,
                          height: 5,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code fort provider

```
 bool showMap = false;

  void showMapPicker(bool showMapP) {
    showMap = showMapP;

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This is the button with `GestureDetector`
to hide and show the widget

```
 GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
        Provider.of < AppData > (context, listen: false)
            .showMapPicker(true);
    },
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
        "assets/edit_loc.svg",
        height: 60,
    ),
),
```

Finally it is the widget itself that i want to show and hide,

```
child: MapPicker(
    iconWidget: SvgPicture.asset(
        //color: Colors.deepPurple,
        "assets/pin.svg",
        height: 40,
    ),
    //add map picker controller
    mapPickerController: mapPickerController,

    showMapPicker:
    Provider.of < AppData > (context, listen: false).showMap,


    child: (GoogleMap(
        mapKey: _mapKe)),

),
```

But nothing happens. The boolean `showMapPicker` is set to false initially, i believe it has changed to `True` after clicking on `GestureDetector` but the state doesn't change.
Do i need to add anything else ? `setState(){}` or sth? Shouldn't provider package take care of that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
child: Consumer < AppData > (
    builder: (context, value, child) => MapPicker(
        iconWidget: SvgPicture.asset(
            //color: Colors.deepPurple,
            "assets/pin.svg",
            height: 40,
        ),
        //add map picker controller
        mapPickerController: mapPickerController,

        showMapPicker: value.showMap,

        child: (GoogleMap(
            mapKey: _mapKey)),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your MapPicker widget, you are not listening to the provider for any new changes, instead you are just reading its value once. You can set the listen parameter to true or not define it at all:

```
showMapPicker: Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: true).showMap,
```

Comment: If you go thru the question again, I have already done that under `child: MapPicker(.....)`

Comment: Yes but you specified listen: false, so this means that you will not be notified of any new changes made in the provider, to listen to changes and rebuild the widget, you must listen to the changes by specifying listen: true.

Comment: thnx but it threw errors, I am using Consumer instead, which works in my case